# It keeps saying "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: math"

Tags: vpython

So I'm supposed to write a Python program that creates 3 circles of spheres: one on the xy plane, one in the yz plane, and one in the xz plane. Each ring should be centered on the origin, and I'm trying to use three while loops to do this, but nothing is working in VPython and I don't know why.

Web VPython 3.2
from visual import *

x = math.radians(360)

n = m = l = 0

while n <= x:
sphere(pos = vector(math.sin(n), math.cos(m), 1), radius = 0.1, color = color.red)
n = n + (math.radians(30))
m = m + (math.radians(30))

n = m = l = 0

while n <= x:
sphere(post = vector(math.sin(n), m, math.cos(1)), radius = 0.1, color = color.blue)
n = n + (math.radians(30))
l = l + (math.radians(30))

n = m = l = 0

while m <= x:
sphere(pos = vector(n, math.sin(m), math.cos(1)), radius = 0.1, color = color.green)
m = m + (math.radians(30))
l = l + (math.radians(30))

Comment: Please format your code block(s), in order to make your question more readable, and receive better quality answers. For more information, take a look on this link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Web VPython (webvpython.org or equivalently glowscript.org) or the vpython module available for use with installed Python (see installation info at vpython.org)? In either case, simply delete all occurrences of "math."; the math library is available without this (and its use with Web VPython gives an error). Also note that the name of the Python module is "vpython", not "visual".